# Database 4 byte UTF-8 support not properly checking

Tags: database

In the status report of my drupal website I got the message that I had to up `Database 4 byte UTF-8 support`. I updated all my tables and database like it's told here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2754539. I checked and all my tables and the database have utf8mb4 encoding and utf8mb4_general_ci collation.

I get the following warning:

> Enabled, but database tables need conversion Please convert all
>   database tables to utf8mb4 prior to enabling it in settings.php. See
>   the documentation on adding 4 byte UTF-8 support for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by manual setting the `drupal_all_databases_are_utf8mb4` variable to `true`. You can do this by using drush or setting it in the database and then clear all caches.